# "You are special" phrase double meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I noticed in several movies and video games (from the top of my head - The Last of Us, Beyond: Two Souls) that when a guy tells a girl "You are special" it actually means that he likes her.

Do I right understand that it's some sort of magic phrase specially for such cases? Do people in all countries understand it or say only in USA? Are there any other double meaning phrases like this I should be aware of?

Comment: Context is very important, alot depends on how or why it is said. On it's own it would usually be understood to mean "You are special *(to me)*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a particular phrase at all. It just means what it means, that she is **different** (in a good or a bad way, depending on the context).

It can very well mean that he likes her, or that she's plain retarded, depending on the sentences before that one and after.

You can even say:

> You are special to me.

Which is even stronger and means that she matters to you in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,You understood its right meaning..it don't have any double meaning.

I think people in almost all countries use this sentence to convey someone(Not  necessary to girl you like only) their feelings.to let them know about their importance.

I  think this magical phrase could be easily understand by that person  also even if he/she not that much good in English :)